# ssh issue after updating mac os 13

Tags: macos, ssh, ventura, tunnel

Im Using ssh tunnel its was working before update, But after update im not able to do ssh on 2nd host.It keep asking me password. Even key is same, first jump host its working. So i don't think issue with my key.

Answer (score 0):

Add to `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host *
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa
```

And it will work

Comment: Please provide some more information on how this specifically solves the question, given that the question doesn't actually provide any logging to indicate the actual error. As it stands it appears to just restate what the OP mentioned in a comment.

Comment: In my case source SSH version is latest and remote server had older version. To support older version too we have to enable this.